# Totaling H:M:S in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

I have an expression that sums up the values of hours, minutes and seconds(HH:MM:SS) in Reporting Services with the expression:

```
    =CStr(sum(CInt(split(Fields!Column.Value,":")(0)))+sum(CInt(split(Fields!Column.Value,":")(1)))\60)
    &":"& CStr(sum(CInt(split(Fields!Column.Value,":")(1))) mod 60+sum(CInt(split(Fields!Column.Value,":")(2)))\60)  
    &":"& CStr(sum(CInt(split(Fields!Column.Value,":")(2))) mod 60)
```

It looked or worked fine until a user spotted that the minute is not being rounded up when we have a value of 60. For example, I have totals like so

```
    5:60:42, 7:60:02 and so on
```

How do I rectify this error in my expression so that the minute values are rounded up correctly when it get to 60?

Comment: What is returning your Column field? Seconds, minutes or hours?

Comment: Column field is in HH:MM:SS

Comment: What type is it? varchar or time?

Comment: The data type is varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should do the trick.

```
=CStr(sum(CInt(split(Fields!Column.Value,":")(0)))+(sum(CInt(split(Fields!Column.Value,":")(1))) + sum(CInt(split(Fields!Column.Value,":")(2)))\60)\60)
    &":"& CStr((sum(CInt(split(Fields!Column.Value,":")(1))) + sum(CInt(split(Fields!Column.Value,":")(2)))\60) mod 60)  
    &":"& CStr(sum(CInt(split(Fields!Column.Value,":")(2))) mod 60)
```

You must first calculate the total of all minutes before you take the `mod 60`.
I'll try and explain using pseudo code, this is for calculating the total minutes:

- Yours (wrong):

> [ (`sum_of_all_min` mod 60) + (`sum_of_all_sec` \ 60) ]

- Correct approach:

> [ `sum_of_all_min` + (`sum_of_all_sec` \ 60) ] mod 60

The same can then be applied when calculating the hours total, you must use the total minute amount before dividing it by 60.

- This is the hour calculation, only the corrected version:

> `sum_of_all_hours` + [ `sum_of_all_min` + (`sum_of_all_sec` \ 60) ] \ 60

---

Example in numbers, imagine you got this:

sum_total_hours = 5
sum_total_min = 59
sum_total_sec = 75

- Using your example would give this:

> 5 + (59 \ 60) **`:`** (59 mod 60) + (75 \ 60) **`:`** (75 mod 60)
>   **=>** 5 + (0) **`:`** (59) + (1) **`:`** (15)
>   **=>** 05:60:15

- Correct approach

> 5 + [59 + (75 \ 60)] \ 60 **`:`** [59 + (75 \ 60)] mod 60 **`:`** (75 mod 60)
>   **=>** 5 + [59 + (1)] \ 60 **`:`** [59 + (1)] mod 60 **`:`** (15)
>   **=>** 5 + [60] \ 60 **`:`** [60] mod 60 **`:`** (15)
>   **=>** 06:00:15